# How to align a text left side while keeping vertically centered?

Tags: plugins

If you see [this page](https://askpuzzle.com/puzzle/what-can-point-in-every-direction-but-can-not-reach-the-destination-by-itself/), text are aligned left side but I also want them to align centered vertically. Similar to **Middle Align + Left Align** in excel.

You can see this image to see what I am looking for [image]

Comment: You need to include more information, it's not easy for us to understand what it is you are asking. :)

Comment: Okay, i have added more details to explain it more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With flex:

```
.question-content-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Without flex:

```
.question-content-text {
    position: relative;
}
.content-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text will need to sit inside an element that has a width and left / right margins. For example, you would use a construct like this...

```
`<span style="width:50%;margin-left:25%;margin-right:25%">Here is my 
 text</span>`
```

Doing it like this will mean your text takes up the middle 50% of the available element, and it will align to the left of that middle 50% (unless you add something like text-align:center).

Most probably, you'll create a class in your custom css, with the attributes as above, and then just use the class wherever you want the text to appear like this.

```
`.my-center-text {width:50%;margin-left:25%;margin-right:25%;}`
```

Comment: Thanks for the time, could you please share the CSS code for the same.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include backticks, so the code should show up now

Answer (score 0):

Use additional CSS rule.

```
.question-content-text{display:flex;align-items:center;}
```